# How to use <object data= with the syntax <object>?

Tags: html, data-uri, html-object

I can only use:

```
<object> data.. </object>,
```

not:

Can I change the syntax:

```
<object data="data:text/html;base64,drgsdrgsdrgsdrgsdrgsdrgsdrg=="></object>
```

into this style:

```
<object>data</object> style?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The child nodes of an object element:

1. Provide *alternative* content in case the object data can't be loaded
2. Are expressed in the form of HTML not a URI

The closest you could get would be to decode the HTML embedded in the URI (despite the claim it is `text/html`, the URI doesn't appear to resolve to anything sane) and then use that instead of having an object at all.

Comment: Can you use <embed src or other syntax to embed the data uri? I can use <embed without closing the tag.